# How to resize JqGrid column width

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, jqgrid

net webform using jqGrid with column Action, Responsible, Target date.
How can i resize the columns. i try to add `width:'116'` on the column but did not work
i don't have any error on my console
my grid looks like this opon adding
[Grid looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLKgV.png)
Here's my code on jqgrid

```
function loadActions(datas) {
//    var  Responsible = Responsible(),
    // Refresh data if jqgrid is already initialized
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid("GridUnload");
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid('clearGridData').trigger("reloadGrid");
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: datas,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        colNames: ['Action','Responsible','TargetDate'],
        colModel: [
           
            { name: 'Batch_no', index: 'Batch_no', sortable: false, editable: true, width:'116' },
             {
                name: 'Responsible',
                index: 'Responsible',
                width: '116',
                sortable: false,
                editable: true,
                editrules: { required: true },
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: { value: {} },
            },
            {
                name: 'TargetDate',
                width: '116',
                index: 'TargetDate',
                sortable: false,
                editrules: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                },
                editable: true,
                width: '70px',
                align: 'center',
                editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (el) {
                        $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
                    },
                    defaultValue: function () {
                        var currentTime = new Date();
                        var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                        month = month <= 9 ? "0" + month : month;
                        var day = currentTime.getDate();
                        day = day <= 9 ? "0" + day : day;
                        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                    }
                }
            },
        ],
//        beforeSelectRow: function (id) {
//            if ($('#' + id).attr('editable') == 1) {
//                return false;
//            }
//        },
        pager: '#Actiongridpager',
        pgbuttons: false,
        pginput: false,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        sortname: 'name',
        multiselect: true,
        height: '100',
        maxheight: '100',
        width: '350',
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 10000
    });
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid({ recreateForm: true })

   // Disable form CRUD
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#Actiongridpager', { edit: false, save: false, add: false, cancel: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false });

    // Enable inline CRUD
    $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#Actiongridpager', { add: true, edit: true, save: true, cancel: true });
    
   
}
```

What i'm doing wrong or what do i need to add . Hope some help me out with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have a question - Why do you first use GridUnload, then clearGridData and then reload the grid and then create it? Another question - which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: jqGrid  4.7.0 i use that because of the drop down outside the jqgrid

Comment: The gridUnload in 4.7 is buggy and in principle after calling it you do not need to call clearData and then trigger grid - that are really not needed operations, since when unloading the grid is destroyed and recreated again.

Comment: $('#Actiongrid').jqGrid({ recreateForm: true }) is not correct setting. The form recreation is a part of form editing options. I recommend you to check the docs

Comment: even though i remove the grid unload and reload grid its still the same